# targeting an 'a' sibling of a hovered list item

Tags: jquery, html

I've got nested navigation on my site. It looks something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a>Main Link 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Sublist Item of Main Link 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a>Main Link 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Sublist Item of Main Link 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>


</ul>
```

I would like to target only `a` link when it's sibling, in this case the `ul`, children are hovered. I'm trying to achieve this with jQuery, but cannot find the right solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see a `div` in your code. Please describe what you intend to do - right now your question is rather confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add some identifying classes to your HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="mainLink">Main Link 1</a>
    <ul class="linkHoverTarget">
      <li>Sublist Item of Main Link 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a class="mainLink">Main Link 2</a>
    <ul class="linkHoverTarget">
      <li>Sublist Item of Main Link 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can register for the hover events and then get to the corresponding link in those hover events like this:

```
$(".linkHoverTarget li").hover(
    function() {
        // get the link in a sibling of our parent ul
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".mainLink");
    }
);
```

This could probably be done with more complicated and fragile selectors without adding identifying classes, but it's certainly not as clear or maintainable as doing it this way.